# CodeIgniter: Send Email from InfinityFree

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, web-hosting

I'm trying to send an email using this code:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from("myemail@email.com");
$this->email->reply_to("myemail@email.com");
$this->email->to("myemail@email.com");
$this->email->subject("Test mail");
$this->email->message("Email body");
$this->email->set_alt_message("Email body txt");
$this->email->send();
```

I just hosted my site in InfinityFree and when I tried sending emails, It's not sending anymore. Can please someone help. My code was working before a hosted it in InfinityFree

Comment: Have you set the email config settings correct https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#setting-email-preferences-in-a-config-file

Comment: $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
            $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
            $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
            $config['smtp_user'] = 'email';
            $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
            $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
            $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

$this->email->initialize($config);  

***I have this config, I'm not sure if it's correct with InfinityFree****

Comment: Put the code in your question not comment